# Steps to remove Ultegra and install SRAM Force disc brakes with internally routed hose

Tags: hydraulic-disc-brake, sram, build

I have a CAAD12 disc with Ultegra, but I prefer SRAM, so I have got some nice new Force levers & calipers that I need to fit. This is my first experience with disc brakes.

The front setup isn't a problem, as the cable is all external, but the rear brake is a bit daunting as the hose is internally routed. Another concern is that the SRAM levers come ready connected to the calipers, with the fluid already in them.

The steps as I see it are:

1. Disconnect Ultegra caliper.
2. Drain hose - or can you get like stopper or bung to keep the oil inside?
3. Attach string to end of hose and pull back through (or some other method to help guide the new hose back through the frame)
4. Disconnect SRAM caliper
5. Drain hose? Or again can you plug it somehow?
6. Easily feed hose through frame in one go without getting cross
7. Install caliper & connect hose
8. Bleed brakes

I've missed out fitting the levers as that's a given. My main worry is getting brake fluid everywhere, and if it is possible to somehow plug the hoses up whilst I'm feeding them through the frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your steps are all correct, I suppose the main issue is how not to spill brake fluid everywhere and how to route housing internally without any frustration. I've been through the same recently and know how annoying the job can be. Apart from draining the system, you have several options:

1. Use a special barb that threads into the hose and has a hole to attach the thread to. The "RockShox Reverb Stealth Barb Connector" can be found on eBay for 10USD. There are other similar products too.
2. Source about two meters of ~5mm 2:1 heat shrink tube and connect it to the old housing before pulling back. You can cover the open end of hose with a piece of plastic bag, the heat shrink should hold it tight enough. Repeat in reverse when routing the new hose. I did this with shifting housing and see no reason why this approach wouldn't work with a hydraulic hose.